# Angular ui-sref-active="active" not working on refresh

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, state

I have the following link

```
<a data-ui-sref-active="active" data-ui-sref="contact" href="javascript:void(0)">
    Contact
</a>
```

It shows as `active` when I go to that page by clicking the link.

But the active class gets removed when I refresh the page.

How can I maintain the active page state when the user refreshes the browser?